# What other theorems about the duality of projective geometry?

Tags: projective-geometry, duality-theorems

> As the real projective plane, PG(2, R), is self-dual there are a
> number of pairs of well known results that are duals of each other.
> Some of these are:
>
> Desargues' theorem ⇔ Converse of Desargues' theorem 
> Pascal's theorem ⇔ Brianchon's theorem 
> Menelaus' theorem ⇔ Ceva's theorem

I get some dual theorem in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)#Dual_theorems). So besides the above theorem, is there any other theorem about duality in projective space? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A century or more ago, projective geometry texts were often written in a two column format, where theorems and their duals (and their respective definitions and proofs) were described side by side.

For example [Hatton's *Projective Geometry*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n175/mode/2up).  The URL I've given points to a sequence of pages written in this format, but if you leaf and skip through the text you'll see many more pages like this, starting all the way back to [the beginning of the text](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n17/mode/2up).

Back in the day, a dual theorem was called "a correlative".  You'll see that term often.  This text, like many others of its day, is an all-you-can-eat buffet of dual theorems.

Since you mentioned Pascal $\iff$ Brianchon, see [Chapter XIV](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n201/mode/2up) for that and two other biggies: Carnot's Theorem and its correlative, and Desargues' Theorem (the 'other' Desargues' theorem about transversals through systems of conics) and its correlative).